# Изменить значения DataFrame на основании другого DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

У меня есть 2 df:

```
d1 = pd.DataFrame({
   'ID':['ABC123', 'ABC124', 'ABC125', 'ABC126', 'ABC127', 'ABC128', 'ABC129', 'ABC130', 'ABC131', 'ABC132'],
   'PRICE':[2365.34, 45.37, 225.25, 574.3, 23.34, 7.98, 2353.34, 79.42, 6554.09, 12.45],
   'CUR':['GBp', 'EUR', 'GBP', 'USD', 'SEK', 'CHF', 'GBp', 'CHF', 'GBp', 'CHF']
})

d2 = pd.DataFrame({
   'RECEIVED_CODE':['GBp', 'AUD'], 
   'CONVERTED_CODE':['GBP','USD'], 
   'CONVERSION_RATE':[100, 1]
})
```

Мне необходимо заменить значения по следующей логике:

если значение `CUR` 1 df совпадает со значением `RECEIVED_CODE` 2 df, то необходимо в данной строке заменить значение самого `CUR` на `CONVERTED_CODE`, а `PRICE` разделить на `CONVERSION_RATE`.

Код:

```
for row in d2.itertuples():
    tmp = d1[d1.CUR == row.RECEIVED_CODE]
    tmp['PRICE'] = tmp['PRICE'] / row.CONVERSION_RATE
    tmp['CUR'] = row.CONVERTED_CODE
    d1.update(tmp)
```

делает то что нужно, но при объеме d1 10кк строк и d2 - 10 строк, данный код отрабатывает несколько минут, что очень долго.

код

```
d1['CUR'] = d1.CUR.map(d2.set_index('RECEIVED_CODE').CONVERTED_CODE).fillna(d1.CUR)
```

может изменить `CUR` на `CONVERTED_CODE`, но приспособить данный метод для изменения `PRICE` у меня не получилось.

Как это можно оптимизировать?

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: можете привести в вопросе пример DF, который вы хотите получить на выходе?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Я бы делал это так:

сначала создаём вспомогательный DF с валютами встречающимися в обоих DF:

```
In [95]: r = (d1.rename(columns={'CUR':'RECEIVED_CODE'})
                .reset_index()
                .merge(d2.rename(columns={'CONVERTED_CODE':'CUR'}), on='RECEIVED_CODE'))

In [96]: r
Out[96]:
   index      ID    PRICE RECEIVED_CODE  CUR  CONVERSION_RATE
0      0  ABC123  2365.34           GBp  GBP              100
1      6  ABC129  2353.34           GBp  GBP              100
2      8  ABC131  6554.09           GBp  GBP              100
```

[DataFrame.eval()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.eval.html) позволяет делать арифметику "на лету":

```
In [99]: r.set_index('index').eval("PRICE = PRICE / CONVERSION_RATE")[['CUR','PRICE']]
Out[99]:
       CUR    PRICE
index
0      GBP  23.6534
6      GBP  23.5334
8      GBP  65.5409
```

воспользуемся этим:

```
In [100]: d1.loc[r['index'], ['CUR','PRICE']] = \
            r.set_index('index').eval("PRICE = PRICE / CONVERSION_RATE")[['CUR','PRICE']]
```

результат:

```
In [101]: d1
Out[101]:
       ID     PRICE  CUR
0  ABC123   23.6534  GBP
1  ABC124   45.3700  EUR
2  ABC125  225.2500  GBP
3  ABC126  574.3000  USD
4  ABC127   23.3400  SEK
5  ABC128    7.9800  CHF
6  ABC129   23.5334  GBP
7  ABC130   79.4200  CHF
8  ABC131   65.5409  GBP
9  ABC132   12.4500  CHF
```